# Authenticating git in a playbook

Tags: git, github, ansible

How can use to authenticate my account on Github?
The ideal way would be supplying a token (Since we are using MFA authentication on our github accounts), but I cannot find a method for supplying them in the git module.

Any help?

Comment: I've never used Ansible, but can't you use a [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used the git module key_file directive in order to let the control machine access github, in it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible uses the config of the host you apply the ansible run to. So you have to make sure, the server on that you apply the playbook can connect to github.

Github has several options. That's not an Ansible specific problem.

Maybe you can add a key to your server which is known by Github.

Comment: I guess that's the right solution. I was hoping there was a way to use an https token, but I don't see a way to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: I would if you're answer was what I'm looking for. I didn't want to authenticate every server with github, only the control machine. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear enough in the question, those were my first days with Ansible and I still had a lot tearn. The answer I added now was the solution I needed to my question. Thanks anyway.